# Why is my ASP.Net Date Format Changing Erratically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, date-format

I have an asp.net 4.0 Formview bound to a SqlDataSource, hosted on IIS7, and I'm displaying a date for editing like this:

```
<input id="OrderDateTextBox" type="text" value='<%# Eval("OrderDate", "{0:d}") %>' />
```

This generally works as expected, but occasionally the date format displays d/m/y instead of m/d/y. When this happens, a page refresh will show the correct date format.

So far I've tried setting the default culture in web.config like this:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

I've also tried setting the culture on initialization:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    UICulture = "en-US";
    Culture = "en-US";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        new CultureInfo("en-US");

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Neither of those methods seem to have any effect. However, if I pull in the value by using the following syntax the date format is correct all the time:

```
<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("OrderDate").ToString()).ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) %>
```

But that shouldn't be necessary. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you certain these are random? Anything in common to the occurrences you have seen?

Comment: Well, it seems to occur after periods of inactivity, maybe after the session expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `{0:d}` and depending on the culture to format the date, you can try forcing the date into the formatting you wish. Example:

```
<%# Eval("OrderDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>
```

Comment: That works! I'd still like to know why it's necessary to do this, just in case the culture is affecting other settings as well, but this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert on .NET culture changes, but I do know how to format dates. Glad this helped you!